# Использование аргумента как функции

Tags: jquery, javascript

подскажите пожалуйста как избавиться от дублирующего кода в jq-плагине на [странице](http://prozaik.16mb.com/js2/form_step/)

проблема в том, что метод step() содержит 2 похожих участка кода:

> $(elem).closest('fieldset').addClass('hide').next().removeClass('hide');
>
> $(elem).closest('fieldset').addClass('hide').prev().removeClass('hide');

хотелось бы чтобы аргумент className использовался непосредственно в цепочке методов. соответственно при этом количество кода сократилось бы в 2 раза. возможно ли такое?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разве что так:

```
var obj = $(elem).closest('fieldset').addClass('hide');
if(className == 'next'){
   obj.next().removeClass('hide');
}
else{
   obj.prev().removeClass('hide');
}
```

можно, конечно, вытащить и функцию по className, но ИМХО не стоит тут изощряться - смысл?

Comment: Если имелось ввиду это то можно сделать так:
$(elem).closest('fieldset').addClass('hide')\[className\]().removeClass('hide');

Comment: ну да, ну да, javascript он такой - гибкий. Тока надо будет проверить, что [className] не undefined, по хорошему

Comment: спасибо. вот это решение понравилось
$(elem).closest('fieldset').addClass('hide')[[_className_]]().removeClass('hide');
а как называется это явление? почитать собираюсь на эту тему..

Comment: className этож просто переменная, второе решение всяко правильнее

Answer (score 1):

```
var $fieldset = $(elem).closest('fieldset').addClass('hide');
$fieldset.next().add($fieldset.prev()).removeClass('hide');
```

Можно так. Кода меньше не стало, но так правильней.

```
$(elem).closest('fieldset').addClass('hide')
.next().removeClass('hide')
.end().prev().removeClass('hide');
```

Или так.